# how to calculate the FIFO depth when the data width is different for reading and writing

Tags: fifo

In my academic project, I need to handle some data using a FIFO. The data will be written to the FIFO at the frequency 156.25Mhz and at each time 66bits data will be written. At the reading side, the clock frequency is 644.53Mhz and at each clock 16bits data will be read. Right now am using 2048 register and the data will be handled using write and read pointers. This works fine for 1 million write clock cycle periods but after that it shows some overflow. what is wrong with my implementation?? Is the register(FIFO) depth not enough?? somebody please help...

Thanks in advance,
ASIF

Answer (score 0):

By simple calculation,

data written in 1 ns: 10.3125

data read in 1ns: 10.31248

data written is slightly more than data read, which will have impact after a long time.

Regards
Akshay